# Widget to convert abc notation to sheet music flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Does anyone have experience or know how I might be able to get sheet music out of abc notation using some package in flutter? I know there is ABCjs library for react guys and looking for something similar.

Just for reference I am trying to convert the following abc into its appropriate sheet music to display:

```
X: 2
T: Full Of Joy
R: polka
M: 2/4
L: 1/8
K: Gmaj
[M:4/4]
d2 de d2 cA|d2 de d2 cA|dedA dedA|c2 BA GA B2|d2 de d2 cA|
ddde d2 cA|dedA dedA|GAED G2 z2||Bc B2 AB A2|GABc A4|c3 B ABAG|
FGAB ABAG|AAAB AAAB|AAAd c3 B|ABcd BcAF|G4 [g2B2D2] z2||
|:d6 eg|d6 e2|g2 ag ed ^c2|d6 z2|d3 e g2 a2|bd' a2 a2 g2|
e3 d ^cd e2|d6 z2|g3 a g2 e2|d3 e g2 a2|dega dged|
A2 =c2c2 BA|d2 d2 d2 eg|d6 cB|ABAG FGAF|G6 z2:|
```

what that abc notation should look like in sheet music : -

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated

I have tried using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/sheet_music), but could not get it to work and seems like it has a few issues which is likely why.

Comment: Just ask how to do it instead of asking for a package recommentdation. See [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic) for why we generally don't do recommendation questions.